# Post form data(select) not available which is created by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have 2 select element in form. first select element is static and second select option change according to first select element.
for this i used jquery ajax. i am getting all things.
The problems comes when i submit the form. i dont get the second select element value.
My code is working in IE.
But not in Chrome and Mozilla.
My html file is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>DATA ENTRY</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>


  </head>
 <body>

 <table class="data_table">
<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="submit_ops.php" />
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="databaseTable" class="databaseTable">
            <option value="">Select Table</option>
            <option value="value1">value1</option>
            <option value="value2">value2</option>
            <option value="value3">value3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="TableColumn">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Continue" name="usubmit"/></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name^=databaseTable]").on("change", function(){
       var val=$(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {"val" : val},
            success: function(result){
                $("#TableColumn" ).html(result);

            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
 </html>
```

When i submit the form the value of TableColumn(second select element) is unavailable.

Comment: is `$("#ColName_"+rowId)` in the `<form>` element?

Comment: are you shure you need to combine POST and GET variables here?

Comment: Hi @Ammar, if below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

change the `data` value for you `$.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php?action=change_column",
            data: {"val" : val+"."+rowId},
            success: function(result){
                $("#ColName_"+rowId ).html(result);

            }
        });
```

**Server Side**

get the passed value with `$_POST['val']`

Comment: Thanks for answer ...ajax is working fine ...ajax is creating form element <select> on submit this form i am not getting the select value..i hope its clear now

Comment: check out edit in the question..

Comment: I am not getting... what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Form(element by ajax)-on submit form variable is not available which is created by ajax...